# Wired ethernet on a Mac mini 2012 with Ubuntu 12.10 problem

Tags: drivers, mac, ethernet

I have a issue with a late mac mini 6.1 2012

Ubuntu: 12.10 Kernel: 3.5.0-25 generic

`lspci -nnk | grep -i net -a3`:

```
00:1f.3 SMBus [0c05]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller [8086:1e22] (rev 04)
        Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:7270]
        Kernel modules: i2c-i801
01:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Broadcom Corporation NetXtreme BCM57766 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe [14e4:1686] (rev 01)
        Subsystem: Broadcom Corporation NetXtreme BCM57766 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe [14e4:1686]
01:00.1 SD Host controller [0805]: Broadcom Corporation NetXtreme BCM57765 Memory Card Reader [14e4:16bc] (rev 01)
        Subsystem: Broadcom Corporation Device [14e4:0000]
        Kernel driver in use: sdhci-pci
        Kernel modules: sdhci-pci
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4331 802.11a/b/g/n [14e4:4331] (rev 02)
        Subsystem: Apple Inc. Device [106b:010e]
        Kernel driver in use: bcma-pci-bridge
        Kernel modules: bcma
```

I cant get wired to work but my wifi works after a install of this package packages.ubuntu.com/quantal/all/linux-firmware-nonfree/downloadU. ,

Now i need to figure out how to get the wired to work. 
but i will come and ask about that if i cant find any post about it.

Answer (score 1):

Based on [these instructions](http://mike.kz/how-to/installing-linux-on-a-late-2012-mac-mini/) I found a link to [installing the driver with DKMS](http://www.frozenindustries.com/2012/11/04/ubuntu-12-04-lts-on-an-apple-mac-mini-late-2012/). I tested this on 12.04 LTS (not 12.10) and it worked with this hardware:

```
01:00.0 0200: 14e4:1686 (rev 01)
Subsystem: 14e4:1686
01:00.0 Ethernet controller: Broadcom Corporation Device 1686 (rev 01)
Subsystem: Broadcom Corporation Device 1686
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16
Memory at a0400000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=64K]
Memory at a0410000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=64K]
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel driver in use: tg3
Kernel modules: tg3
```

I've copied the relevant instructions here as requested.

Install any pending kernel updates, and the `dkms` package. Check that you are running a Linux kernel version 3.5 or later. If you upgraded the kernel, you must reboot with the new kernel before you will be able to load the driver.

Accept the [Broadcom license](http://www.broadcom.com/support/license.php?file=570x/linux-3.124c.zip) and download and install the [latest drivers for 3.5 and higher kernels](http://mike.kz/linux-3.124c_3.5_KERNELS.zip). Extract the ZIP file and move its contents to `/usr/src/tg3-3.124c/src`:

```
unzip linux-3.124c_3.5_KERNELS.zip
sudo mkdir /usr/src/tg3-3.124c
sudo mv tg3-3.124c /usr/src/tg3-3.124c/src
```

Create a file called `/usr/src/tg3-3.124c/dkms.conf` with the following contents:

```
PACKAGE_NAME=tg3
PACKAGE_VERSION=3.124c
CLEAN="make -C src/ clean"
MAKE="cd src/ && make BUILD_KERNEL=${kernelver} KVER=${kernelver}"
BUILT_MODULE_NAME[0]="tg3"
BUILT_MODULE_LOCATION[0]="src/"
DEST_MODULE_LOCATION[0]=/updates
AUTOINSTALL=yes
```

Run the following commands to compile and install the driver:

```
sudo dkms add -m tg3 -v 3.124c
sudo dkms build -m tg3 -v 3.124c
sudo dkms install -m tg3 -v 3.124c
```

And load the driver:

```
sudo modprobe tg3
```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.